# Как рассчитать новые координаты зная вектор?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Вопрос скорее по математике, с которой у меня всё очень плохо. Есть объект находящийся на координатах (0,0,0). Он вращается по оси Y. Требуется по нажатию на любую клавишу переместить его на указанное заранее расстояние в сторону взгляда. Проще говоря есть вектор (Длина и угол относительно оси). По какой формуле можно получить координаты после перемещения?

Comment: Коодинаты - это составляющие вектора? Опишите подробнее, что вам надо вычислить. К примеру у вас ничего не вращается, а просто есть шарик, у него есть позиция. У вас есть вектор направления камеры (которой вы управляете?). Как передвинуть шарик по вектору камеры на указанное расстояние? Я правильно понял вопрос?

Comment: Не совсем, как передвинуть шарик зная его угол поворота относительно оси Y. Камера статична.

Comment: @aepot - у человека вращение в координатной плоскости (XOZ) и он не может умножить длину вектора на sin и cos от угла поворота, и сложить их исходными координатами объекта - ИМХО случай безнадежный.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мой ответ будет относительно **Unity** и его возможностей, математики будет минимум, это более линейное решение без траектории:

Возьмем ваш **GameObject** которому нужно предугадать позиции и убедимся, что направление взгляда - совпадают направлению **синей оси в локальном пространстве**.

Чтобы узнать, какое пространство сейчас отображается или как его сменить : в **Unity** редакторе можно сменить **World** на **Local** на панели выбора инструмента для манипулирования объектами, обычно это в левом верхнем углу редактора.

Когда мы знаем, что направление взгляда это **Forward**, можно приступать предугадывать позицию.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class LinearPosPrediction : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Update()
    {
        if(Input.anyKey)
        {
            Transform someTransform = transform; // Трансформ вашего объекта
            var distance = 10f; // Дистанция которая вам известна для предугадывания

            var prediction = someTransform.forward; // Получаем направление взгляда (линейно)
            prediction *= distance; // делаем длину вектора больше
            prediction = someTransform.localPosition + prediction; // Вот и собственно линейное предугадывание.

            someTransform.localPosition = prediction; // Перемещаем объект в предугаданную позицию (линейно)
        }
    }
}
```

> Проще говоря есть вектор (Длина и угол относительно оси). По какой
> формуле можно получить координаты после перемещения?

```
prediction *= distance; // делаем длину вектора больше
prediction = someTransform.localPosition + prediction; // Вот и собственно линейное предугадывание.
```

Аналогично, если направление взгляда это ваша камера, то наверняка камера смотрит по оси **Z** - это нам и нужно, тогда код выше подойдет и для камеры.

Но если вы хотите перемещать другой объект, относительно того как ваша камера смотрит, то вам нужно развернуть **управляемый** объект в направление камеры, после этого применить предугаданные позиции в **локальном** пространстве. Можно применить перемещение без вращения управляемого объекта но, перемещения должны быть в **мировом** пространстве.

```
someTransform.position = prediction;
```

Если предугадывание позиции на **3D** ландшафте, то это не то решение которое вам нужно. Так как наверняка вы хотели бы проверять наличие стен или, чтобы вы не провалились под ландшафт и т.д.

Если вы пытаетесь реализовать **Траекторию** или подобно ей, то есть уроки, как это реализовать проще, красивее, расширяемо.  [Урок по траектории](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zue7-KAnHkg)

> Прекрасный ответ, спасибо, есть еще небольшой вопрос. Возможно ли
> успользуя этот код, двигать не объект SomeTransform, а какой либо
> другой? То есть есть кубик, он крутится, мы получаем направление его
> взгляда, задаем дистанцию, и по нажатию кнопки двигаем не его а
> допустим цилиндр под ним, или любой другой, не важно. Просто в этом
> коде не объявляется никаких public объектов, и вешаем мы скрипт на сам
> куб, поэтому как внедрить сюда какой-то другой обьект не понимаю,
> заранее спасибо. – SuddenDumb

Я не знаю как отвечать на комментарий по этому расширяю ответ..

```
using UnityEngine;

public class LinearPosPrediction : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float PredictDistance = 10f; // назначаем в инспекторе или передаем значение из другого кода, по умолчанию 10
    public Transform Subobject = null; // назначаем в инспекторе или передаем ссылку из другого кода, по умолчанию отсутствует.
    private Transform _selfTransform = null; // кэшируем ссылку на собственный трансформ, можно избавиться если не нарвится..

    public void SubobjectTranslate(Transform subobject, Vector3 position) // можно перемещать из друго-го скрипта, так же можно локально.
    {
        if (subobject == null)
        {
            Debug.LogError($"{this} : Отсутствует ссылка на подобъект !!!");
            return;
        }
        subobject.localPosition = position; // Перемещаем объект в позицию (линейно)
    }
    public Vector3 ForwardPrediction(float distance) // предугадывание позиции, только компактно записано.
    {
        if(_selfTransform == null)
        {
            _selfTransform = transform;
        }
        return _selfTransform.localPosition + (_selfTransform.forward * distance);
    }

    private void Start() // кэшируем ссылку на собственный трансформ, а если вызов Start не был, то ссылка установится в другом месте.
    {
        _selfTransform = transform;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.anyKey)
        {
            var prediction = ForwardPrediction(PredictDistance); // получаем предугаданную позицию
            SubobjectTranslate(Subobject, prediction); // перемещаем подобъект в новую позицию
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Прекрасный ответ, спасибо, есть еще небольшой вопрос. Возможно ли успользуя этот код, двигать не объект SomeTransform, а какой либо другой? То есть есть кубик, он крутится, мы получаем направление его взгляда, задаем дистанцию, и по нажатию кнопки двигаем не его а допустим цилиндр под ним, или любой другой, не важно. Просто в этом коде не объявляется никаких public объектов, и вешаем мы скрипт на сам куб, поэтому как внедрить сюда какой-то другой обьект не понимаю, заранее спасибо.

Comment: @SuddenDumb Да конечно. Я добавлю ответ с цитированием на комментарий. Проверяйте обновления ответа.

Answer (score 3):

Постараюсь дать развернутый более полный ответ. А там как получится.

Предположим, у вас есть двухмерное изображение объекта и вы хотите его вращать в пространстве.

Четыре угла изображения:

```
UL = (0,0)
UR = (NS, 0)
BR = (NS, NL)
BL = (0, NL)
```

где:

- `NS` - ширина
- `NL` - высота

Теперь рассмотрим картинку, как если бы она была на вертикальном прямоугольнике с центром и направлением, параллельным плоскости Y=0.

Пусть единицы координат будут пикселями. Тогда четыре угловые точки станут точками:

```
UL = (X, Y, Z) = (-NS2, 0 , NL2)
UR = (X, Y, Z) = (NS2, 0, NL2)
BR = (X, Y, Z) = (NS2, 0, -NL2)
BL = (X, Y, Z) = (-NS2, 0, -NL2)
```

где

- `NS2 = (NS – 1)/2`  определяет координату горизонтального центра
- `NL2 = (NL – 1)/2`  определяет координату вертикального центра

Рассмотрим перспективную камеру как расположенную на расстоянии `f` = фокусному расстоянию (в единицах эквивалентных пикселям) за изображением, глядя прямо в центр изображения. При этом `Yc = -f`, где `F` определяется `fov` (полем зрения), определенным диагональным размером изображения.

```
tan(fov/2) = sqrt (NS^2 + NL^2) / (2 * f)
```

или

```
f = NS / (2 * tan (FOV/2))
```

где `fov` = эквивалент `fov` для 35-миллиметровой картинной рамки размером 36 х 24 мм. Таким образом,

```
fov = 180 * atan(36/24) / pi ≈ 56 градусов
```

Затем повернём угловые точки прямоугольного изображения на три угла `pan`, `tilt` и `roll` с помощью комбинированной матрицы вращений `R`.

Пусть 3 угла поворота будут определены в следующем порядке:

- `pan` = праворукое положительное вращение точек вокруг оси Z.
- `tilt` = праворукое отрицательное вращение точек вокруг оси X.
- `roll` = праворукое положительное вращение точек вокруг оси Y.

Затем формируется комбинированная матрица вращения:

```
R00 = (croll * cpan) + (sroll * stilt * span)
R01 = (croll * span) - (sroll * stilt * cpan)
R02 = (sroll * ctilt)
R10 = - (ctilt * span)
R11 = (ctilt * cpan)
R12 = (stilt)
R20 = - (sroll * cpan) + (croll * stilt * span)
R21 = - (sroll * span) - (croll * stilt * cpan)
R22 = (croll * ctilt)
```

где приставки `s` и `c` означают `sin()` и `cos()`

Затем проецируйте поворотные точки на камеру в перспективе.

Поскольку `Xc = Zc = 0`, перспективные уравнения становятся:

```
Xp/F = (X - Xc) / (Y – Yc) => Xp = f * X / (Y + f)
Zp/F = (Z – Zc) / (Y – Yc) => Zp = f * Z / (Y + f)
```

Но нам нужно преобразовать из `Xp` в `S` (образец) и `Zp` в `L` (линию) так, чтобы `S,L` были в левом верхнем углу, а не в центре, и `L` увеличивалась вниз.

```
Xp = - NS / 2 + S
Zp = NL / 2 – L
```

где:

- NS = количество образцов (ширина)
- NL = количество линий (высота)

Посчитаем.

```
ss1 = 0
sl1 = 0
ss2 = NS - 1
sl2 = 0
ss3 = NS - 1
sl3 = NL - 1
ss4 = 0
sl4 = NL - 1

NS2 = (NS - 1) / 2
NL2 = (NL - 1) / 2
ws1 = NS2
wl1 = NL2
ws2 = NS2
wl2 = NL2
ws3 = NS2
wl3 = - NL2
ws4 = - NS2
wl4 = - NL2

X1 = (ws1 * R11) + (wl1 * R13)
Y1 = (ws1 * R21) + (wl1 * R23)
Z1 = (ws1 * R31) + (wl1 * R33)
X2 = (ws2 * R11) + (wl2 * R13)
Y2 = (ws2 * R21) + (wl2 * R23)
Z2 = (ws2 * R31) + (wl2 * R33)
X3 = (ws3 * R11) + (wl3 * R13)
Y3 = (ws3 * R21) + (wl3 * R23)
Z3 = (ws3 * R31) + (wl3 * R33)
X4 = (ws4 * R11) + (wl4 * R13)
Y4 = (ws4 * R21) + (wl4 * R23)
Z4 = (ws4 * R31) + (wl4 * R33)
```

Таким образом, перспективные уравнения становятся:

```
S = ((f * X) / (Y + f)) + NS2
L = NL2 - ((f * Z) / (Y + f))

S1 = ((f * X1) / (Y1 + f)) + NS2
L1 = NL2 - ((f * Z1) / (Y1 + f))
S2 = ((f * X2) / (Y2 + f)) + NS2
L2 = NL2 - ((f * Z2) / (Y2 + f))
S3 = ((f * X3) / (Y3 + f)) + NS2
L3 = NL2 - ((f * Z3) / (Y3 + f))
S4 = ((f * X4) / (Y4 + f)) + NS2
L4 = NL2 - ((f * Z4) / (Y4 + f))
```

Теперь спроецируйте четыре повернутые угловые точки по этим уравнениям.

```
Smax = max( S1, S2, S3, S4 )
Smin = min( S1, S2, S3, S4 )
Lmax = max( L1, L2, L3, L4 )
Lmin = min( L1, L2, L3, L4 )

delS = Smax - Smin + 1
delL = Lmax - Lmin + 1

if (delS > delL){
    del = delS
    ofsS = 0
    ofsL = (NL - (delL * NS / $dels)) / 2
} else {
    del = delL
    ofsL = 0
    ofsS = (NS - (dels * NL / $dell)) / 2
}

dS1 = ofsS + ( ( S1 - Smin ) * NS / del )
dL1 = ofsL + ( ( L1 - Lmin ) * NL / del )
dS2 = ofsS + ( ( S2 - Smin ) * NS / del )
dL2 = ofsL + ( ( L2 - Lmin ) * NL / del )
dS3 = ofsS + ( ( S3 - Smin ) * NS / del )
dL3 = ofsL + ( ( L3 - Lmin ) * NL / del )
dS4 = ofsS + ( ( S4 - Smin ) * NS / del )
dL4 = ofsL + ( ( L4 - Lmin ) * NL / del )
```

Наконец, получили четыре точки проецируемые с четырьмя исходными точками изображения и теперь можем использовать эти координаты в проекции искажения перспективы.

```
[ sS1, sL1 ] => [ dS1, dL1 ]
[ sS2, sL2 ] => [ dS2, dL2 ]
[ sS3, sL3 ] => [ dS3, dL3 ]
[ sS4, sL4 ] => [ dS4, dL4 ]
```

Оригинальное изображение

[image: Оригинальное изображение]

pan = 45˚

[image: pan = 45]

tilt = 45˚

[image: tilt = 45]

roll = 45˚

[image: roll = 45]

pan = 45˚, tilt = 45˚

[image: pan = 45, tilt = 45]